# Cannot add ReactiveMongo to Play-Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

ers,

I am having troubles with integrating the ReactiveMongo within the Play framework. My build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.9"
)
```

When I try to run the server with the play run command I get the following error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.reactivemongo#play2-reactivemongo_2.9.2;0.9: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.reactivemongo#play2-eactivemongo_2.9.2;0.9: not found
```

The think that goes wrong is clear; it is looking for the 2.9.2 Scala version of the library. I have no idea why SBT is looking for 2.9, I have 2.10 installed. I have tried on several machines.

```
$ scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.10.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

and

```
$ play    
play! 2.1.3 (using Java 1.7.0_25 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you're not using a Play2.0 application ? Even if the play command-line indicates 2.1.3, the application you're trying to start might be a 2.0 one. Please check project/plugins.sbt file for a line like

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.3")
```

If play tries to search for a 2.9.2 version of reactivemongo then play is using 2.9.2 version of scala (and thus it look like you're using a 2.0 version)

Answer (score 1):

Reactive Mongo requires Scala 2.10 and you're trying to get it with 2.9. http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Creactivemongo

try (note the `%` instead of `%%`):

```
"org.reactivemongo" % "play2-reactivemongo_2.10" % "0.9"
```

Comment: You're also probably using an older version of Play. Check your project's Play version in `/project/plugins.sbt`

Answer (score 1):

```
With single % instead of %% , dependency is not found ...i have changed my
```

scala version and now things are working fine , 
below is my build.sbt snapshot:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" % "play2-reactivemongo_2.10" % "0.10.2"
)
```